Nvim+Treesitter gives me language highlights in markdown code blocks, how do I set custom highlights?
When writing technical documentation in markdown, Neovim and Treesitter will provide language formatting for triple back-tick code blocks ```cpp
For example:
int main() { printf("hello world\n"); }

How can I define some simple custom rules for my own code block format, for example ```foo?
# A comment
/home/user/somefilePat
Just some normal text with number 12345.576 formats

I realise that I could create my own custom TreeSitter grammar, but that is a lot of work.
Is there any way of leveraging vim's built-in formatting mechanism for this? Just using a few simple regex mappings? Something I could add to my init.lua config?
